# exported PDF in Jasper Report lost last line but IReport designer works fine

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have an issue related to wrapping of text in pdf format. i have use below jrxml and datasource to generete pdf, and it works fine in iReport preview mode. However, it lost last line in exported PDF. It only triggered when the text width was very close to the field width

Anybody have and idea of what's could by wrong?

---

Here is the JRXML source

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report3" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="515" leftMargin="40" rightMargin="40" topMargin="100" bottomMargin="20" uuid="95b76e31-975e-4830-af1c-53ca2b77f1dc">
<queryString language="xPath">
    <![CDATA[/pdfg_report_data//record-detail]]>
</queryString>
<field name="examination" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[examination]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<detail>
    <band height="31" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="173" y="15" width="322" height="15" uuid="e1ef4821-5eae-4bc3-8a8b-ac0a6d58b0f1"/>
            <box topPadding="1"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="11" isBold="false" pdfEncoding="Cp1251"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{examination}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Here is the XML datasource

```
<pdfg_report_data> 
<record-detail>
    <examination>CT Thorax(Plain+Contrast), CT Aen(Plain+Contrast), CTabcd(Plain+Contrast), CT Nasopharynx(Plain+Contrast), CT qwerasdf</examination>
</record-detail>
</pdfg_report_data>
```